# Calling function from another class show Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

There are two classes. `Class1` and `Class2`. `Class2` has one function with argument, i call the function of class from class one. it show a `Null Pointer Exception error`.

Class1:
         `Class1` calling the function of `Class2`

```
try{
    String name="vijay";
    Sends obj=new Sends();
    obj.fun(name);

  }catch(Exception e){
      Toast.makeText(GoodActivity.this, e.toString()+"good", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

Class2: `Class2` function

```
  public void fun(String s){
     Toast.makeText(Sends.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

Comment: where is NPE? post your log output

Comment: Send is an `Activity`. You must not use the new operator on a class that extends `Activity`

Comment: then how can i do that @blackbelt

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Show a Toast in another Activity?

Comment: when i am calling function from another class it shows null pointer exception...@joao2fast4u

Comment: Sends is the name of Class2 ? Please post the entire code snippet and also logs if possible.